# IS UNDEFINED INDEX error is only limited to xampp 

Tags: php, xampp

The following code give undefined index in XAMPP but not on other APACHE Server is this error only limited to xampp

```
<?php
    if($_POST['names']!=""&&$_POST['n']!="")
    {
    print_r($_POST);
    }
?>

<form action="undefiend_error.php" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="names" value="">
<input type="text" name="n" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="nd" value="">
<input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined index/variable error is limited to **erroneous code** only.

An erroneous code would always produce an error, despite of the system you running. You can use some settings to gag the error message, **but the error itself will remain in your code.**

So, **you have to corrrect the error,** not error message.

To correct this one you have to check if there is should be a variable or not. The Wouter's method above os okay. So,

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) 
{ 
  print_r($_POST); 
}
```

will raise an error only when there is absent required field - the thing error messages are for.

Answer (score 1):

This error will indeed be present on all systems, but your XAMPP server likely has `display_errors = on` in php.ini. If you view the error log of a server where you don't see the warning on screen, it should be logged unless `error_reporting = 0` . If you don't see the error on other systems, that doesn't mean it isn't occurring - PHP is just configured not to show or log it.

You need to use `isset()` to test if the `$_POST` value is there, or you'll get an undefined index notice:

```
// Check that both `$_POST['names']` and `$_POST['n']` exist with `isset()`
if(isset($_POST['names']) && isset($_POST['n']) && $_POST['names'] != "" && $_POST['n']!="")
{
  print_r($_POST);
}
```

Comment: the cause is apparently not display_errors but error_reporting value. in fact, there are no word 'display' in the opening post.

Comment: no this code is runnig properly on my one machine but error on machine with XAMPP

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Already added another bit about `error_reporting`

Comment: @VasudhaivaKutumbakam The point is, this code will issue an undefined index warning on ANY PHP system where error_reporting is turned on.  The code needs to be fixed as I have it above, and it will stop producing errors on your XAMPP system (which reports errors) and any other system you run it on which does not report errors.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check if the form is submitted:

```
<?php
  if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' )
  {
     // Form submitted
  }
?>
```

And then you should use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) to check if a post item is set.
And at least you can use [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) to check if a post item is empty (or NULL or 0)

Answer (score -2):

PHP reminds you that every variable you use must be defined first. Or, if it coming from outside, checked for existence. try this

```
if(!empty($_GET))?$vars=$_GET:$vars=error;
echo $vars['n'];
echo $vars['names'];
```

Comment: $_GET never being empty. and this code will produce the same error